# Anticipated Delphi Switch

Tags: node, protocol

When is the Tezos mainnet expected to switch to Delphi?

Is there anything that node owners should do in anticipation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything goes as expected, the network should switch to proto 7 in ~18 days (Thu, 12 Nov 2020 10:47:01 GMT).

```
Sun Oct 25 22:41:40 UTC 2020

$ tezos-client show voting period

Current period: "promotion_vote"
Blocks remaining until end of period: 25207
Current proposal: PsDELPH1Kxsxt8f9eWbxQeRxkjfbxoqM52jvs5Y5fBxWWh4ifpo
Ballots: { "yay": 6476, "nay": 0, "pass": 22592 }
Current participation 34.21%, necessary quorum 56.37%
Current in favor 6476, needed supermajority 5180
```

Agora Link: https://www.tezosagora.org/period/36

About the nodes, it should be fine since this proposal didn't include sapling.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade your node to version 7.4 or 8.0~rc1 you won't need to download the new protocol from your peers so the activation will be simpler and this also lets you check before the activation that the protocol compiles.